# Restart Service C# when error occurs in event

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a service that monitors a folder and performs actions.

This is working perfectly.

However if I deliberately throw an exception within the event method that is called when a file is created, my service stops.  I thought that windows automatically tries to start a service again if it stops, but it looks like this is not the case.

There are several examples for restarting a service which I can use, but I am just wondering if I am missing something obvious here?

It looks as though I will need to put something into my overall try/catch block to restart the service?

This is the method that sets up the folder watcher:

```
    public void Start()
    {
        var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderToMonitor"];
        var path = string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting) ? "c:\\temp\\spreadsheets": setting;

        var processedPath = path + "\\Processed";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(processedPath);

        var errorsPath = path + "\\Errors";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(errorsPath);

        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = path,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                           NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                           NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                           NotifyFilters.FileName |
                           NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                           NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                           NotifyFilters.Security |
                           NotifyFilters.Size,
            Filter = "*.*",
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        _watcher.Created += OnFileCreated;
    }
```

When a file is created this event is called

```
   private void OnFileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
     while (!IsFileReady(e.FullPath))
     {
     }

     Process(e.FullPath);
  }
```

Here I am now deliberately throwing an exception:

```
    public virtual void Process(string filename)
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
        var processedPath = path + "\\Processed";            
        var errorsPath = path + "\\Errors";

        var filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(filename);

        try
        {
            ReadFile(filename);

            if (filename.Contains("hello"))
            {
                throw new Exception("TEST ERRROR");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e, "Error processing file");
            File.Move(filename ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), $"{errorsPath}\\{filenameOnly}");

            throw;
        }

        Log.Information($"File processed {filename}.  Moved to processed folder");
        File.Move(filename ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), $"{processedPath}\\{filenameOnly}");
    }
```

If I try to restart the service myself using the code below

```
var service = ServiceController.GetServices("My Service Name").FirstOrDefault();
            if (service?.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                service.Start();
            }
```

I get the error

```
'Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'My Service Name'. This operation might require other privileges.'
```

I have double and tripled checked - my service name is correct.  I am also running Visual Studio in Admin mode.

The service is being run as the **Local System** user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[Local System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/localsystem-account)** account has does not have the [privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/service-security-and-access-rights) to interact with the Service Control Manager (SCM), which you're attempting to do.

You need to run the service with a different account with those privileges.

If you must run as **Local System**, then I suggest you configure the SCM itself to restart the service. Most sys admins will prefer this anyway because they can control what happens. It's a non-programmatic solution.

Comment: Thanks ideally I would like to have the service installed with the force restart options set but no major issue if that has to be done manually

Comment: Local System account has minimal privileges ? The following seems to contract this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/localsystem-account
`It has extensive privileges on the local computer, and acts as the computer on the network`

Comment: I meant minimal when compared to an admin, so my answer was a bit misleading. I corrected that and added in your link. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It says "this operation might require other privileges" , but it should not since you said it is running with admin privileges but still lets give this a try.

Go to Add a new item and add an application manifest file to your project

Change

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="isInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

To

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This might fix your problem, make sure you run the released version of your application instead debug.